# Paradoxical css rule `.myClass:hover { display:none; }` has no effect

Tags: css, google-chrome

**Preamble:** This is a somewhat 'academic' question. I'm looking for an explanation and intelligent conjecture, not a practical solution (there is no real problem to "solve").

So, I notice that if I make a `:hover` selector set its `display` property to `none`, it has no discernible effect in Chrome (v23). In fact, no other properties in the selector are applied. It's as if the entire selector is ignored.

e.g.

```
<div class="myElement">Hover over this. Nothing happens!</div>
```

...

```
.myElement:hover {
  display:none;
  color:red;
}
```

(**Check out the [jsFiddle of this](http://jsfiddle.net/MnZyx/1/)**)

Obviously, since an element with `display:none` cannot be hovered, the element is instantly no longer becomes selected by the `:hover` selector, so loses the `display:none` property (and becomes eligible for selection again).

The paradoxical nature of this rule leads me to wonder why (for example) the `display` property doesn't toggle rapidly (every frame, or mouse move) as it does in other browsers (ie9, firefox). Although I think I prefer Chrome's implementation, I wonder why the other properties (e.g. `color:red`) aren't applied.

The question: is there some official documented reason why Chrome chooses to bail on this silly selector, or is this some kind of bug?

Answer (score 4):

> The question: is there some official documented reason why Chrome chooses to bail on this silly selector, or is this some kind of bug?

After looking at the render events that occur when you hover the link, it looks like Chrome actually renders this change in display (I originally thought Chrome was ignoring it for performance reasons). In 1.65s, it captured 11360 events recalculating style and layout because of this change in display.

So why don't you see a flicker? Chrome is rendering the change at such a fast rate you won't see the change (or the browser just doesn't render it). When you switch to visibility: hidden, you see that flickr because the item is still in the render tree, just hidden (plus, it's slower, a lot less render events are firing).

> I wonder why the other properties (e.g. color:red) aren't applied.

It's cascading, so the display: none is applied, then the red color. The same reason why you never see the hover state is the same reason why you don't see the color change.

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1, but this statement "It's cascading, so the display: none is applied, then the red color." doesn't sound right. They're two completely different properties, so the cascade is irrelevant. If you move the `color` declaration above you'll see that there's still no effect, for the very reason in your statement that just follows this one.

Comment: Good correction -- thanks. The point I was trying to make was that you'll never see the color change because of the display change.

Comment: If the rule was toggling "too fast to see", I would expect a random flickering between the two states, rather than no effect at all. That doesn't quite sit right with me. Do you understand what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think `display:none` and `hover` at same time is causing the confusion to the browser. It works with `visibility:hidden` though.

```
display:block;
visibility:hidden;
color:red;
```

you can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/MnZyx/2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was hoping for more specifics than that it's "confusing" the browser, though.